# angularjs, tree directive with check boxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Can any one direct me for angular js tree directive with check boxes. I have come across few but none of them are fully functional with check boxes.Even the angular ui tree, http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-ui-tree,  I don't find samples with check boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote a directive on this, with which you could have as many levels of checkboxes as you like. Basically it checks recursively after click events, and emit/broadcast them accordingly. Check out [the repo](https://github.com/Luxiyalu/angular-checkbox-set), and [the live demo](http://luxiyalu.com/playground/checkbox/).

Comment: Thanks Luxiyalu for the nice directive. If I have come across any issues will update you on Github.

Comment: Amazing :) just perfect

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, angular-ui-tree allows you to edit the node template so you can place a checkbox on each node and bind it to a property of the node.

Comment: Yes Boluc, the method you mentioned works. Let me try and post to forum  if I stuck up somewhere. Meanwhile, instead I reinventing the wheel, if some body has any reference code to achieve this please direct me. Thanks.

Comment: Finally 80% is completed. Categories and subcategories are not appearing and in the json, even if checked : true, tick mark is not appearing in the check box. please see my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/TvzW7IVEp0eCnftigkey?p=preview. my code is in groups.js. Can any one help me to fix the code, please?